# Combine mongo $push and $currentDate to include time in new array element

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to add a new document to a mongo array and I require one of the fields to be the current timestamp. This is for field level versioning but I can't figure out how to combine $push and $currentDate to get the result I would like.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
db.tmp.adviceReportingJourney.update(
    { _id : "5525f99be4b041151d51386e5525f99be4b041151d513870" },
    {
        $push: {
            "$currentDate": {
                "Conversation1MeetingCreated" :  {
                    "vid" : 4,
                    "ts" : {"$type": "timestamp"},
                    "data" : 1428552213559
                }
            }
        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use your coding language date.Now to add the current time ;-) 
Like (i asume java;-)):

```
db.tmp.adviceReportingJourney.update(
    { _id : "5525f99be4b041151d51386e5525f99be4b041151d513870" },
    {
        $push: {
            "$currentDate": {
                "Conversation1MeetingCreated" :  {
                    "vid" : 4,
                    "ts" : {"$type": "timestamp"},
                    "data" : Date.now()
                }
            }
        }
    }
)
```

UPDATE: When running mongo > 3.0 you could use $currentDate. From the documentation [$currentDate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/currentDate/) it shows that $currentDate only works on db.collection.update(), db.collection.findAndModify().

See the example below to update the embedded document "Conversation1MeetingCreated" (where you update the timestamp) use:

```
{
  $currentDate: {
        "Conversation1MeetingCreated.ts": { $type: "timestamp" }
     }, 
  $set: {
        "Conversation1MeetingCreated.vid" : 4,
        "Conversation1MeetingCreated.data": 1428552213559
     }  
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I'm using Python and was thinking I might need to do that but I thought that Mongo should be able to handle it, because I want my dates to be in a consistent format across the database and all the other collections are using the Mongo Timestamp.

Is it not possible to achieve this with $push?

Comment: Thank you. Will give this try tomorrow

Comment: I'm not sure this always the case. The whole idea of using $currentDate inside such queries is to rely on MongoDB's cluster time, not on your local machine time.